# What does "shrug" mean in "Atlas shrugged"?

Tags: word-meaning, verbs

I've been reading ["Atlas Shrugged"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlas_Shrugged) and the title puzzled me.

> The title is a reference to Atlas, a Titan in Greek mythology, who is described in the novel as "the giant who holds the world on his shoulders". The significance of this reference appears in a conversation in which Francisco d'Anconia asks Rearden what advice he would give Atlas if "the greater [the Titan's] effort, the heavier the world bore down on his shoulders". With Rearden unable to answer, d'Anconia gives his own advice: "**To shrug**".

Those are two famous versions of Atlas with the globe on his shoulders:

[image]
[image]

> The sculpture depicts the ancient Greek Titan Atlas **holding the heavens on his shoulders.**

The words that come to my mind are **scoop, crouch, bend**. But I couldn't find whether **shrug** is synonymous with any of them.

The common (and only) meaning seems to be inappropriate.

> raise (one's shoulders) slightly and momentarily to express doubt, ignorance, or indifference

Comment: That one and only meaning is the one.  It works on a couple of different levels.  First, the physical expression of the shrug disrupts the continuity of the Earth.  Second, the causation of this disruption, Atlas, seems indifferent about the effects.

Comment: That is a _very bad_ book. Not just the writing, but the ideas and philosophy.

Comment: Shrugging is when you raise and lower your shoulders to show you don't care, don't know or are exasperated. "I told you I didn't know the answer to that question", she said as she shrugged her shoulders. //Yeah, the book and author are bad news: very right wing and mean.

Comment: If the world was really supported on a giant's shoulders, we wouldn't want him to shrug his shoulders, would we?

Comment: The writing of Atlas Shrugged is not remarkably bad -- that's simply not true. As for the ideas and the philosophy, Rand saw firsthand what Soviet Russia did to the individual. I find it hard to fault her given that. She knows exactly what government control of all aspects of life leads to.

Comment: I think it's important to remember the differences between Objectivism and other political philosophies out there.

Comment: Shrugging expresses indifference because it symbolically represents a move to shake off a burden. In the context of that book, it means that all the ablest people might shake off the burden of supporting all the other people, leaving them to their fate. It's a rather arrogant, elitist, foolish book.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey One still needs to read it to arrive (or not) at this conclusion. I am quite surprised you all have a strong (and negative) opinion about it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Atlas is normally depicted holding the heavens or the world on his shoulders.  He may be depicted crouching or stooping under the weight, but the important thing is that he is carrying it on his shoulders.

Anconia is not suggesting that Atlas do the same thing he has always been doing.  If you are holding something on your shoulders and then you shrug, what happens?  It falls off.  So Anconia is suggesting that Atlas "shrug off" the weight that is on his shoulders.